# Can "in" follow "but also"?

Tags: grammaticality

I wrote

> My experience at the seminar made me realize **that there** is incredible value in not just doing mathematics but also **in discussing** it with **other people**.

and a reputed software suggested an improvement, namely

> My experience at the seminar made me realize **there** is incredible value in not just doing mathematics but also **discussing** it with **others**.

What's correct? I noticed that the second version doesn't have "in" following "but also", but I am not sure if the two sentences carry the same meaning. How do I effectively convey my ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Because there are no such things as "softwares", saying "a software" in ungrammatical. The word *software* is a mass noun like *silverware* or *clothing* or *happiness*, not a count noun like *warehouse* or *program* or *item*.

Comment: Your version does not seem obviously wrong. Software like Grammarly is not always correct.

Comment: The problem is parallelism, not in the "but also" part. Parallelism would ask for #2: "in not just A but B." #1 has "in not just A but **in** B."

Comment: ... 'Parallelism would ask for #2' ...  or  #3: ... value not just in doing mathematics but also in discussing it with others.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone! I liked Edwin's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, the software suggested it "as an improvement". You didn't break any rules of grammar in what you wrote, the software just sees it as a better way of writing the same thing, and I'm inclined to agree with it.

The 'improvement' just makes it more concise. You have already used the word "in" to prefix the previous list item, so there is no need to repeat it.

Consider a list like this:

> You can use this product:
>
> - in bathrooms
> - in kitchens
> - in bedrooms

This needlessly repeats the word 'in'. Instead, we could have placed the word once after the word 'product'.

Lists in sentences can be abbreviated in similar ways:

> You can use this product in bathrooms, kitchens and bedrooms.

Your original sentence 'lists' two things, both with the same preposition:

> My experience at the seminar made me realize that there is incredible value **in** not just doing mathematics but also **in** discussing it with other people.

Removing the second isn't a requirement, but it does read better.

Comment: I believe that there is a grammar error in OP's original sentence. You say that there are two prepositional phrases, each beginning with "in", but in that case "not just" and "but also" do not function as a correlative pair, which is how they normally function.